# jQuery function not working inside sweetalert2 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert2

I'm using sweetalert2 modal in which I have a bunch of cards with a link tag and upon clicking the link tag a function updates a hidden input's value. the function does not works. but when I manually inject the JavaScript via console it begins to work. I have tried defining the function above the main code and below the main code but still no luck.

Here's the sweetalert code

```
  $(a_gateway2).click(function() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: '<strong>Select Coin</strong>',
      html:
        `<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
        <div class="card shadow-new">
           <div class="card-body">
              <a class="coin_card card-block stretched-link text-decoration-none" data-coin="bitcoin" href="#">
              <div class="row" >
                 <div class="col-4">
                    <img src="assets/img/bitcoin.svg" alt="Bitcoin">
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-8">
                    <span>Bitcoin</span>
                 </div>
              </div>
              </a>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>`,
        showCancelButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false
    })
    });
```

and my function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a.coin_card").click(function(){
        var value=$(this).attr('data-coin');
          $('#gateway-value').val( value );               
             return false;
      });
  });
```

HTML

```
 <input type="hidden" value="" id="gateway-value">
```

Comment: Hi, your content are dynamically created so you need to bind it with static elements i.e :`$(document).on("click","a.coin_card",function(){ //your codes })`

Comment: This worked thanks!